# Analysing data with multinomial logistic regression

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, spss, multinomial-logit

I am trying to analyse a dataset with multinomial logistic regression. The data looks as follows: 1 categorical dependent variable with 4 levels (Same-day delivery, Next-day delivery, Evening delivery, and Pick-up point) + 1 categorical predictor with 5 levels (Control condition and 4 treatment conditions, let's call them TC1, TC2, TC3 and TC4). I want to know whether the number of people who selected the "pick-up point" varies between the different condition. The syntax + output:

```
NOMREG Delivery_mode (BASE=LAST ORDER=ASCENDING) BY Condition
  /CRITERIA CIN(95) DELTA(0) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(5) CHKSEP(20) LCONVERGE(0) PCONVERGE(0.000001) 
    SINGULAR(0.00000001) 
  /FULLFACTORIAL
  /STEPWISE=PIN(.05) POUT(0.1) MINEFFECT(0) RULE(SINGLE) ENTRYMETHOD(LR) REMOVALMETHOD(LR)
  /INTERCEPT=EXCLUDE
  /PRINT=CELLPROB CLASSTABLE FIT PARAMETER SUMMARY LRT CPS STEP MFI.
```

[image]

So this analysis tells me that basically overall in all conditions people chose pick-up point significantly less often than the other delivery modes. However, this is not what I am interested in. I want to know whether the proportion of pick-up point choices is different across conditions. If I switch the IV and DV in the syntax I get that information. See the output below. This appears to tell me that, relative to the control condition, in every treatment condition more people picked the 4th delivery option, which was the pick-up point).
[image]

However, that analysis does not make sense I think; the delivery choice cannot predict the condition participants were in... right?

In other words: how do I need to proceed with this analysis to answer the main research question?

Thanks for your help in advance; this is the first time I conducted an RCT with a categorical DV so I'm completely new to these types of analyses.

Comment: Do you just have that one predictor variable?

Comment: @Dave, Yes, just the one predictor variable!
As part of the dataset there are also many demographic variables that I would be interested in exploring later on, but I want to figure out this analysis first :)